# A short-range alternative to LiDAR

Tags: lidar, point-cloud

LiDAR is a very popular choice for long distance applications such as autonomous vehicles. I'm looking for a device that can give me a 3-dimensional representation of a close proximity environment (e.g. a 5-10 meter diameter "sphere" of points.) Are there cheaper versions of LiDAR that can fit this situation, or is there another technology to look at instead?

I've considered cameras, but would prefer a more "physical" representation of the surroundings.

Comment: Have you looked at depth cameras, like the Intel Realsense 435 or the Luxonis Oak-D?

Comment: Good recommendation, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is borderline into a ["shopping question"](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) that aren't a great fit for the site. To that end I'm going to answer you in as generic a way as possible.

Commonly available LIDARs can have ranges out to ~100m but there are many of them with shorter maximum ranges or effective ranges in the 10s of meters. Some drop down into single digit meters of range. There's a large range of options with different fields of view. There are multi-beam spinning ones, the more classic single plane ones. And it can drop down to single beam ones too.

There are specialized ones also that are focused on very close range. Think milimeters not meters.

Alternative technologies can include depth cameras. (Unlike your assertion they do provide 3D information like a LIDAR, and often provide color information as well.) The most classic is stereo cameras which rely on texture in the environment. There are also classes of structured light cameras that project patterns usually in IR out. There are limitations of structured light is bright environments such as outside.

There's also ultrasonic sensors which are much cheaper but much coarser in their results.

The cost of different sensors can range by 6 orders of magnitude and their update rates can range potentially by 3 or 4. The field of view is very variable, from 360 to single point.

All of this comes together to say that there's a lot of options out there and is why we don't want shopping questions. Because we can't make all the design tradeoffs without actually fully knowing your requirements of your application which can't be effectively captured in a post on this forum.

Comment: Apologies for a slightly unfit question. Thanks for the answer nonetheless. :)